# QGIS 1.8 fails to rotate point geometries with rule-based style

Tags: qgis, point, style

I have to do some visualizations in QGIS (1.8.0) and up to now I've been very happy with the new Dialog "Layer Properties -> Style", using the rotation-field to rotate Point-Geometries visualized by a triangular Symbol of the section "Simple Markers".

For me QGIS fails to rotate Point-Geometries with rule-based style. Here what I did:

I've got a Point Layer with a Attribute table with this structure:

```
ID ; Place   ; orientation ; typ        ; centrality
1  ; Basel   ; NULL        ; center     ; 2
2  ; Liestal ; 120         ; depending  ; 4
3  ; Munzach ; 123         ; depending  ; 5
```

Under the "Categories"-Section I made two categories: 'center' and 'depending'. The Symbol of the depending Place is rotated, using the 'orientation'-column as the rotation field. Now it shows on the center place.

Now I'm trying to use the "Rotation field" in the "Rule-based"-Section which doesn't work for me. I Want to scale the Place according to their centrality.

In the 'rule-based' section I added a rule with the Filter typ='depending' and I disabled the Symbol. then I did 'refine current rule' -> 'add categories to rule'. Here I classified the Column 'centrality' and added my triangular Symbol in different sizes according to the centrality of the place. This works. Now I want those triangles to show to the center place using the -> Advanced -> rotation field -> 'orientation'.

Unfortunately QGIS doesn't apply the rotation field in Layers with 'ruled-based' Symbology.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Update: This issue should be fixed now

---

Old answer:
This is a known problem: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5915. If you have development skills or funds, you can help fix it.

Otherwise, you can try workarounds using other renderers.